# How to get workitem of File from ACC use APS?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Hi Autodesk Forge Team !

How can we get workitem of Revit file from ACC? I find some tutorial but just see use process upload file, I want get direct latest version from source urn like:

```
"resourceUrn" : "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.rXJhqUE6QamM6ANpG2Qz6w?version=1",
```

[image]

It will be good if can help me provide a .NET example to intergrate with server side.
I'm tried with that one but it not working

```cs
using Autodesk.Forge;
using Autodesk.Forge.DesignAutomation.Model;
using Autodesk.Forge.Model;
[TestCase("b.ca790fb5-141d-4ad5-b411-0461af2e9748","urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.rXJhqUE6QamM6ANpG2Qz6w?version=1")]
[Test]
public async Task BuildDownloadURL(string projectId, string versionId)
    {
        VersionsApi versionApi = new VersionsApi();
        versionApi.Configuration.AccessToken = Token;
        dynamic version = await versionApi.GetVersionAsync(projectId, versionId);
        dynamic versionItem = await versionApi.GetVersionItemAsync(projectId, versionId);

        string[] versionItemParams = ((string)version.data.relationships.storage.data.id).Split('/');
        string[] bucketKeyParams = versionItemParams[versionItemParams.Length - 2].Split(':');
        string bucketKey = bucketKeyParams[bucketKeyParams.Length - 1];
        string objectName = versionItemParams[versionItemParams.Length - 1];
        string downloadUrl = $"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/{bucketKey}/objects/{objectName}";

        XrefTreeArgument xrefTreeArgument = new XrefTreeArgument()
        {
            Url = downloadUrl,
            Verb = Verb.Get,
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "Authorization", "Bearer " + Token }
            }
        };
        Assert.IsNotNull(xrefTreeArgument);
    }
    [TestCase("result.rvt")]
    [Test]
    public async Task BuildUploadURL(string resultFilename)
    {
        string nickName = "chuong";
        string bucketName = "revitdesigncheck" + nickName.ToLower();
        BucketsApi buckets = new BucketsApi();
        buckets.Configuration.AccessToken = Token;
        PostBucketsPayload bucketPayload = new PostBucketsPayload(bucketName, null, PostBucketsPayload.PolicyKeyEnum.Transient);
        try
        {
            await buckets.CreateBucketAsync(bucketPayload, "US");
        }
        catch { }

        ObjectsApi objects = new ObjectsApi();
        dynamic signedUrl = await objects.CreateSignedResourceAsyncWithHttpInfo(bucketName, resultFilename, new PostBucketsSigned(5), "readwrite");

        XrefTreeArgument xrefTreeArgument = new XrefTreeArgument()
        {
            Url = (string)(signedUrl.Data.signedUrl),
            Verb = Verb.Put
        };
        Assert.IsNotNull(xrefTreeArgument);
    }
```

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that for files stored with APS, the best way to pass upload and download URLs to Design Automation is through urn and token, just like the code you shared does. This is explained in [this blog post](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/new-feature-support-direct-s3-migration-inputoutput-files-design-automation).

From the interface you shared, I can see that you're trying to run the workitem from the Visual Studio Code extension. For that, you can pass the token in the header and urn in the value.

The correct urn for the input, in this case, is under the `data.relationships.storage.data.id` field from the [GET Versions](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-GET/) response.
It should look just like the one below:

`urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/9f8bdc3f-e29c-4ada-ab7b-bb8dfa821163.pdf`

Comment: Thank you for your help, after put url and result, my process pass now. Can we ignore result output ?

Comment: The output URL will be in the same format if you're storing the result file in APS. 

In the case of your custom OSS buckets, you can simply pass an urn for a non-existing object like `urn:adsk.objects:os.object:yourbucketkey/yourfilecreatedfromworkitem.pdf`

Comment: I mean can we ignore output, because I had another process transfer data to azure, and don't need save data to bucket storage